# ms access replace function Upper Lower letter mess

Tags: vba, ms-access, replace

I have a string and I need to replace some characters. I have until now the following vba code and I have some question to ask.

```
Dim strx As String

strx = rec("Name")
strx = Replace(strx , "a", "&#956;", , , 0)
strx  = Replace(strx , "A", "&#924;", , , 0)
strx = Replace(strx , "b", "&#957;", , , 0)
strx  = Replace(strx , "B", "&#925;", , , 0)
etc... until last letter...
```

My code is working, but it mess up Upper Case letters to Lower Case.

How can I force to replace only the Upper Case letters with something and Lower Case with something else?

```
strx = "Alex Nero - ID12 - Age12 - no more data - Code:A5f7HMnbwi34"
```

As we can see in my vba code i need to replace "A" with something and "a" with something else. The code mess up "A" and "a".

Comment: You are providing `0 = vbBinaryCompare` as parameter `Compare`, so this should work. And it does work in my testing. Please provide your exact code and exact input data and the output you get. -- *mess up* is not a helpful error description.

Answer (score 1):

`Replace()` with `Compare:=vbBinaryCompare` *does* distinguish lower and upper case letters.

```
Sub TestReplace()

    Dim strx As String

    strx = "Alex Nero - ID12 - Age12 - no more data - Code:A5f7HMnbwi34"
    Debug.Print " In: " & strx

    strx = Replace(strx, "a", "&#956;", , , vbBinaryCompare)
    strx = Replace(strx, "A", "&#924;", , , vbBinaryCompare)
    strx = Replace(strx, "b", "&#957;", , , vbBinaryCompare)
    strx = Replace(strx, "B", "&#925;", , , vbBinaryCompare)

    Debug.Print "Out: " & strx

End Sub
```

Output, with highlight on the different replacement of `A` and `a`:

```
 In: Alex Nero - ID12 - Age12 - no more data - Code:A5f7HMnbwi34
Out: &#924;lex Nero - ID12 - &#924;ge12 - no more d&#956;t&#956; - Code:&#924;5f7HMn&#957;wi34
     ^^^^^                                         ^^^^^
```